# Can i use c# to call ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have an ajaxtoolkit for pop up look like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
TargetControlID="Button4"
BehaviorID="popup1" 
PopupControlID="Panel1"
DropShadow="true"
CancelControlID="Button3"
OnOkScript="OkButtonClick"
BackgroundCssClass="BackgroundStyle" />
```

how can i make it execute inside the btnReject_click at c#?

```
protected void btnReject_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//code here
}
```

at first i make it like this.

```
                tb.Text = "Reject";
                tb.CssClass = "btn btn-default";
                tb.OnClientClick = "javascript:$find('popup1').show();";
                tb.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
                tb.CausesValidation = false;
                tb.Click += new EventHandler(btnReject_click);
```

but i find that it will execute the pop up first. so, currently i'm looking a way to make it execute after the button is click

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have delete button dynamic generate depends on table row. then when it click, popup will appear ask user to enter the reason then submit. currently the dynamic button i put its id = the row. so i get to know which row and get the identity key of the row. i'm new in asp.net. as the process goes, it gets more complicated.